# Exceeding the DB size limit on SQL Server Express in READ_ONLY

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, licensing, sql-server-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

If my database is larger than 10GB and I'm using it in READ_ONLY mode, will I be violating the licensing agreement somehow?

It appears that SQL Server Express edition only gets fussy if you try to insert data into a DB larger than the limit, but reading is fine it appears.

In my case, the READ_ONLY DB will be smaller than the limit, but I'm curious to know if this is a 'legal' use of the software (i.e. scaling out reads across lots of static, large DBs served by Express edition)

Comment: Closed as duplicate? This is completely unrelated to the linked question on 'licensing in general'. The above question relates only to a potential loop-hole in the licensing of SQL Server Express Edition.

Answer (score 2):

If it's really a read only database and assuming no single table is larger than 10GB, you could break off a few tables to a separate DB and then set up views from one db into the other.

Comment: That's a very sensible architecture! Though since I've already got a working application this sounds a lot like work to me. It's the licensing that I'd like to know about though: is >10GB READ_ONLY kosher?